# How to use the TARMAC tracer with gem5?

Tags: gem5

I've noticed that gem5 has a TARMAC tracer at: https://github.com/gem5/gem5/blob/05c4c2b566ce351ab217b2bd7035562aa7a76570/src/arch/arm/tracers/TarmacTrace.py

This seems to be the format also used by FastModels: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0532c/CHDHFCEE.html and might make comparing execution easier.

How to enable that tracer in gem5, e.g. in `fs.py`?

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem to be exposed in any config as of 9048ef0ffbf21bedb803b785fb68f83e95c04db8, but you can easily enable it with a tiny hack patch, e.g. on fs.py:

```
diff --git a/configs/example/fs.py b/configs/example/fs.py
index 4d2165884..e3b74ebeb 100644
--- a/configs/example/fs.py
+++ b/configs/example/fs.py
@@ -374,5 +374,7 @@ if buildEnv['TARGET_ISA'] == "arm" and not options.bare_metal \
             sys = getattr(root, sysname)
             sys.dtb_filename = create_dtb_for_system(sys, '%s.dtb' % sysname)

+for cpu in test_sys.cpu:
+    cpu.tracer = TarmacTracer()
 Simulation.setWorkCountOptions(test_sys, options)
 Simulation.run(options, root, test_sys, FutureClass)
```

Then, if you run `gem5.opt --debug-file`, the debug file `m5out/trace.txt` is saved in TARMAC format instead of the usual format that is controlled by `--debug-flags`.